# Sails/Waterline: How to retrieve relations inside a relation?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I need to retrieve an object and also get the relations and nested relations.

So, I have the three models below:

User model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    pets: {
      collection: 'pet',
      via: 'owner',
    }
}
```

Pet model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    owner: {
      model: 'user'
    },
    vaccines: {
      collection: 'vaccine',
      via: 'pet',
    }
}
```

Vaccine model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    pet: {
      model: 'pet'
    }
}
```

Calling `User.findOne(name: 'everton').populate('pets').exec(....)` I get the user and associated Pets. How can I also get the associated vaccines with **each** pet? I didn't find references about this in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this issue as well, and as far as I know, nested association queries are not built into sails yet (as of this post).

You can use promises to handle the nested population for you, but this can get rather hairy if you are populating many levels.

Something like:

```
User.findOne(name: 'everton')
  .populate('pets')
  .then(function(user) {
    user.pets.forEach(function (pet) {
      //load pet's vaccines
    });
  });
```

This has been a widely discussed topic on sails.js and there's actually an open pull request that adds the majority of this feature. Check out https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/1052

Comment: Thanks @Kevin! Well, I'll implement this way you've indicated. When they finally add this funcionality to the framework, I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of Kevin Le is correct it can get a little messy, because you're executing async functions inside a loop. Of course it works, but let's say you want to return the user with all pets and vaccines once it's finished - how do you do that?

There are several ways to solve this problem. One is to use the [async library](http://caolan.github.io/async/) which offers a bunch of util functions to work with async code. The library is already included in sails and you can use it globally by default.

```
 User.findOneByName('TestUser')
   .populate('pets')
   .then(function (user) {

     var pets = user.pets;

     // async.each() will perform a for each loop and execute
     // a fallback after the last iteration is finished
     async.each(pets, function (pet, cb) {

       Vaccine.find({pet: pet.id})
         .then(function(vaccines){

           // I didn't find a way to reuse the attribute name
           pet.connectedVaccines = vaccines;

           cb();
         })

     }, function(){
       // this callback will be executed once all vaccines are received 
       return res.json(user);
     });
   });
```

There is an alternative approach solving this issue with bluebird promises, which are also part of sails. It's probably more performant than the previous one, because it fetches all vaccines with just one database request. On the other hand it's harder to read...

```
User.findOneByName('TestUser')
  .populate('pets')
  .then(function (user) {

    var pets = user.pets,
        petsIds = [];

    // to avoid looping over the async function 
    // all pet ids get collected...
    pets.forEach(function(pet){
      petsIds.push(pet.id);
    });

    // ... to get all vaccines with one db call 
    var vaccines = Vaccine.find({pet: petsIds})
      .then(function(vaccines){
        return vaccines;
      });

    // with bluebird this array...
    return [user, vaccines];
  })

  //... will be passed here as soon as the vaccines are finished loading
  .spread(function(user, vaccines){

    // for the same output as before the vaccines get attached to 
    // the according pet object
    user.pets.forEach(function(pet){

      // as seen above the attribute name can't get used 
      // to store the data
      pet.connectedVaccines = vaccines.filter(function(vaccine){
        return vaccine.pet == pet.id;
      });
    });

    // then the user with all nested data can get returned
    return res.json(user);

  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon, I`ll try this approach too